# RVM: trouble installing libyaml package on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, rvm, yaml

I'm using RVM 1.13.4 on Mac OS 10.6.8, with XCode 3.2.6. The upgrade to Snow Leopard was fairly recent, and I believe that's when I started having this problem.

When I run `rvm pkg install libyaml`, I get the following error:

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/tsherif/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/tsherif/.rvm/src
Prepare yaml in /Users/tsherif/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Configuring yaml in /Users/tsherif/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/tsherif/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/tsherif/.rvm/log/yaml/make.log


Database file /Users/tsherif/.rvm/config/packages does not exist.
```

Not sure what the story is with `config/packages`. The `make.log` file contains the following:

```
[2012-05-06 05:37:14] make 
make  all-recursive
Making all in include
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I../include   -g -O2 -MT api.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/api.Tpo -c -o api.lo api.c
../libtool: line 787: X--tag=CC: command not found
../libtool: line 820: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
../libtool: line 787: X--mode=compile: command not found
../libtool: line 953: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
../libtool: line 954: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
../libtool: line 984: libtool: warning: cannot infer operation mode from `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2': No such file or directory
../libtool: line 7011: libtool: you must specify a MODE: command not found
../libtool: line 7012: Try `libtool --help' for more information.: command not found
make[2]: *** [api.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems like the shell is trying to execute arguments to `libtool` as commands before passing them to `libtool`? The commands aren't found so the string `command not found` is passed to `libtool`, which then spews out a bunch of error output that `sh` tries to execute and, of course, fails to do. Does it maybe have something to do with the `X`s that seem to be added to the `--tag` and `--mode` options? That's my best guess, anyway, given my limited understanding of `libtool` and `make`.

I've tried adding the following options, based on similar questions I've seen on SO, but to no avail:

- `--with-gcc=clang`
- `--enable-shared`

I've also tried installing `libyaml` separately (without RVM) using both MacPorts and compiling from source, but neither worked. And oddly enough, if I install Psych as a gem after installing Ruby, there's no problem (but I do want it compiled with Ruby).

Comment: Have you tried installing with Homebrew? It makes most of dependency packages very easy to install https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew, then run 'brew instal libyaml'

Comment: @bruno077 Um... that was ridiculously easy. I had also tried installing with MacPorts, but that didn't work, so I figured why bother with another package manager? Homebrew = magic? Anyway, if you want to put this as an answer, I'll select/upvote it. And thanks!

Comment: Homebrew IS magic, I don't know why, but whenever I get into some lib issues, Homebrew seems to have a package ready to solve it. I'm glad you could solve your problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried installing with [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)? It makes most dependency packages very easy to install, then run `brew install libyaml`.